# Log username in maillogs when there is SASL authentication failure

Tags: postfix, saslauthd

I have a server with postfix and `cyrus-sasl`. When ever there is an authentication failure it reports in `maillog` below line.

```
postfix/smtpd[27669]: warning: unknown[185.xxx.xxx.xxx]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: authentication failure
```

How can I make it so that it will also report the username that failed in the log file ( like `SASL LOGIN authentication failed: authentication failure for bob` )?

Answer (score 4):

Try setting the logging level as
  log_level:4
in smtpd.conf ( might be  /usr/lib/sasl2/smtpd.conf )

```
*log_level controls the level of verbosity of messages sent to the syslogd service.
0 no messages
1 unusual errors
2 all authentication errors
3 log non-fatal warnings
4 more verbose than 3
5 more verbose than 4
6 traces of internal protocols
7 traces of internal protocols, including pass-words*
```

In /etc/postfix/master.cf, add -v  after a process like

```
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd -v
```

You can also debug a specific client IP-address by setting theh following in master.cf

```
debug_peer_list = 192.168.0.1
```

Comment: Works fine but too bad it also logs successful logins/passwords

Comment: (supplement) Set more than one v (-v -v) if you want to set greater than or equal to debug level. https://github.com/vdukhovni/postfix/blob/7c53eb5ae9a5fe2f3a3f90c8af0701fc06a5e729/postfix/src/xsasl/xsasl_cyrus_log.c#L78